# Is it more cost effective to level multiple star at once?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

For example:
It takes the following amounts of resources to level the characters:

```
Unlock      100     10
1* to 2*    10K     15
2* to 3*    20K     25
3* to 4*    100K    30
4* to 5*    250K    65
5* to 6*    500K    85
6* to 7*    1M      100
```

- Taken from http://www.swgohcantina.com/star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes-beginners-guide/

So to level a char from 1* to 7* it would take 1,880,100 credits and 330 shards.

Is it somehow more efficient to level the char from 1* to 7* in one go or will I have to pay for each level subsequently and end with the same amount of shards and credits?

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that characters always cost 100 Credits to unlock, regardless of the Star tier they unlock at. So a character that unlocks at 4 Stars will cost 1,750,100 to fully upgrade, and character that unlocks at 5 stars will cost 1,500,100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost is exactly the same no matter what — you can only go up one star level at a time anyways, even if you have enough shards for immediately leveling again.

Note that you can increase multiple training levels at once, but the training droid and credit cost is exactly the same there as well.